# iPython %lprun on function within class

Tags: python, ipython

I'm wondering how to do %lprun on a python script in a class stucture.

Say I want to see what's taking so long in run():

example.py

```
def outside_call():
    mc = MLIC()
    mc.run()

class MLIC(object):

    def __init__():
        pass
    def run():
       #Profile this function
```

Normally if run() wasn't in a class, I would use:

```
%lprun -f example.run example.run()
```

Now I need like...

```
%lprun -f example.MLIC.run() example.outside_call()
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I assume that `example = MLIC()`? What do you mean by `example.outside_call()` as far as I see it, `outside_call()` is not a method of your `MLIC` class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot.

In this case, you can actually do:

```
%lprun -f example.MLIC.run() example.outside_call()
```

I thought I tried it but typed it wrong.